# Extract data between two tags

Tags: awk, sed, grep

After searching and reading extensively, I managed to get half of the work done.

Here is the string:

```
<td class='bold vmiddle'> Owner CIDR: </td><td><span class='jtruncate-text'><a href="http://3.abcdef.com/ip-3/encoded/czovL215aXAubXMvdmlldy9pcF9hZGRyZXNzZXMvNDIuMjI0LjAuMA%3D%3D">42.224.0.0</a>/12</span></td>
```

I need to extract the `42.224.0.0` and `/12` to make a `42.224.0.0/12`.

Now I managed to get `42.224.0.0` by using:

```
sed -n 's/^.*<a.href="[^"]*">\([^<]*\).*/\1/p'
```

but I'm at a loss how to extract `/12`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: with grep if you have pcre, `grep -oP '^.*<a.href="[^"]*">\K[^<]*|</a>\K[^<]*' ip.txt | paste -d '' - -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close:

```
sed -n 's/^.*<a.href="[^"]*">\([^<]*\)<\/a>\([^<]*\).*/\1\2/p' file
```

All that was needed was a 2nd capture group: `<\/a>` after the 1st one matches the closing tag for `<a>`, and the 2nd capture group, `\([^<]*\)`, then captures everything up to but not including the closing `</span>` tag.
`\1\2` in the replacement string simply concatenates what the two capture groups matched, yielding `42.224.0.0/12` with the sample input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below awk solution -

```
vipin@kali:~$ awk -F'>|<' '{print $(NF-6),$(NF-4)}' OFS="" kk.txt
42.224.0.0/12
```

Need to use multiple multiple`(>,<)` field seperators.