# Extract multiple data between multiple, same tags

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Further to the solution in [Extract data between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393877/extract-data-between-two-tags), of which extract one set of CIDR, now we just come across something more complex.

The result returned is as follow:

```
<tr><td class='bold vmiddle'> Owner CIDR: </td><td><span class='jtruncate-text'><a href="http://3.abcdefg.com/ip-3/encoded/czovL215aXAubXMvdmlldy9pcF9hZGRyZXNzZXMvODAuMjQ1LjIyNS4w">80.245.225.0</a>/24, <a href="http://3.abcdefg.com/ip-3/encoded/czovL215aXAubXMvdmlldy9pcF9hZGRyZXNzZXMvODAuMjQ1LjIyNi4w">80.245.226.0</a>/23, <a href="http://3.abcdefg.com/ip-3/encoded/czovL215aXAubXMvdmlldy9pcF9hZGRyZXNzZXMvODAuMjQ1LjIyOC4w">80.245.228.0</a>/22, <a href="http://3.abcdefg.com/ip-3/encoded/czovL215aXAubXMvdmlldy9pcF9hZGRyZXNzZXMvODAuMjQ1LjIzMi4w">80.245.232.0</a>/22, <a href="http://3.abcdefg.com/ip-3/encoded/czovL215aXAubXMvdmlldy9pcF9hZGRyZXNzZXMvODAuMjQ1LjIzNi4w">80.245.236.0</a>/23, <a href="http://3.abcdefg.com/ip-3/encoded/czovL215aXAubXMvdmlldy9pcF9hZGRyZXNzZXMvODAuMjQ1LjIzOC4w">80.245.238.0</a>/24</span></td></tr>
```

It has 6 CIDR:

80.245.225.0/24, 80.245.226.0/23, 80.245.228.0/22, 80.245.232.0/22, 80.245.236.0/23, 80.245.238.0/24

In fact, for other queries we don't know how many CIDRs would be returned.

What solution in bash should we use? Expand the sed string in the linked question? Or something completely different?

Can anyone help?

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this could help you;

```
grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}</a>/[0-9]{1,2}' yourFile | sed 's/<\/a>//'
```

Eg;

```
user@host:/tmp$ grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}</a>/[0-9]{1,2}' test | sed 's/<\/a>//'
80.245.225.0/24
80.245.226.0/23
80.245.228.0/22
80.245.232.0/22
80.245.236.0/23
80.245.238.0/24
```

Comment: Perfect! Very versatile!